# Website doesn't load in firefox/safari ( Linux, OS X )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

Have problem with loading website. This is SPA ( angularjs 1.5v ). In Firefox and Safari doesn't load. Tested on Linux and OS X . When open that site no any errors.

In others browsers works as expected.

Do you have any ideas? What need check etc.

Thanks for help!

Comment: We are not oracles. You should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)